# Why the shooting and the animations working only for one npc and not also to the second duplicated npc?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script that attached to empty GameObject name Shooting :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Shooting : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Main")]
    public GameObject npc;
    public Transform[] firePoints;
    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    public float launchForce = 700f;
    public bool automaticFire = false;
    public float bulletDestructionTime;

    [Space(5)]
    [Header("Slow Down")]
    public float maxDrag;
    public float bulletSpeed;
    private bool bulletsSlowDown = false;
    public bool overAllSlowdown = false;
    [Range(0, 1f)]
    public float slowdownAll = 1f;

    private Animator anim;

    private void Start()
    {
        anim = npc.GetComponent<Animator>();
        anim.SetBool("Shooting", true);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (overAllSlowdown == true)
        {
            Time.timeScale = slowdownAll;
        }

        if (isAnimationStatePlaying(anim, 0, "AIMING") == true)
        {
            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == false)
            {
                if (anim.GetBool("Shooting") == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
            else if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && automaticFire == true)
            {
                automaticFire = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                {
                    automaticFire = true;
                }
                if (automaticFire == true)
                {
                    anim.Play("SHOOTING");
                    LaunchProjectile();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void LaunchProjectile()
    {
        foreach (var firePoint in firePoints)
        {
            Rigidbody projectileInstance = Instantiate(
                bulletPrefab,
                firePoint.position,
                firePoint.rotation);

            projectileInstance.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 0, 1) * launchForce);

            if (bulletsSlowDown == true)
            {
                if (projectileInstance != null)
                {
                    StartCoroutine(AddDrag(maxDrag, bulletSpeed, projectileInstance));
                }
            }

            if ((automaticFire == true || automaticFire == false) && bulletsSlowDown == false)
            {
                projectileInstance.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().destructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
                projectileInstance.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AddDrag(float maxDrag, float bulletSpeed, Rigidbody rb)
    {
        if (rb != null)
        {
            float current_drag = 0;

            while (current_drag < maxDrag)
            {
                current_drag += Time.deltaTime * bulletSpeed;
                rb.drag = current_drag;
                yield return null;
            }

            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            rb.drag = 0;

            rb.gameObject.AddComponent<BulletDestruction>().destructionTime = bulletDestructionTime;
            rb.gameObject.GetComponent<BulletDestruction>().Init();
        }
    }

    bool isAnimationStatePlaying(Animator anim, int animLayer, string stateName)
    {
        if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(animLayer).IsName(stateName))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

[image: Shooting]

In the shooting script at the Npc it's getting the Sci-Fi_Soldier object child of the Sci-Fi_Soldier-Prefab. The Sci-Fi_Soldier have the Animator component.

And this is working fine with the first Sci-Fi_Soldier-Prefab.

But the second duplicated Sci-Fi_Soldier-Prefab (1) is just keep walking non stop and not like the first one. I wanted that the script will control and work on all the Sci-Fi_Soldier-Prefabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shooting script defines one

```
Public GameObject npc;
```

This is the npc that is working. It makes no reference to the other duplicated NPC, and as such is not effecting it. If you changed npc to a list of GameObjects like

```
List<GameObject> npcList;
```

and add all of your NPCs to it, then change your actions to operate on every member of the list, it will effect all of them.